# iframe displays correctly in Chrome, but not in Firefox and IE

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox, html, iframe

Hi i'm using a div wrapper to display an iframe. Right now, the iframe only shows like it should in Chrome. In internet explorer, it's not scale. In Firefox it is scaled, but the position on the screen is wrong.

It's on this page: 
http://www.mobach-groothandel.nl/emka/emka/

Here's the div html:

```
<div id="emkaframe"><iframe height="100%" width="100%" src="http://www.emka-watches.ch/Site/Design_EN/Design.html" scrolling="no"></iframe></div>
```

Here's the css:

```
#emkaframe {
    width:630px;
    height:630px;
    scrolling: no;
    border: 0px;
    -moz-transform:scale(0.70,0.70);
    -moz-transform-orgin: 0 0;
    -o-transform: scale(0.70);
    -o-transform-origin: 0 0; 
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.70);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

Right now, the iframe only shows like it should in Chrome. In internet explorer, it's not scale.
In Firefox it is scaled, but the position on the screen is wrong.
Does anybody have an answer to solve this for Firefox, Chrome and IE?

Comment: What IE version? Why do you think that using WebKit, Opera, and Mozilla vendor-prefixed styles will somehow work in IE?

Comment: Hi Eric, IE10. I missed a part

Comment: Ok.. I have a <div> css to take care for IE10/9. And iframe css to take care for chrome and firefox (latest versions).

Comment: #frameemka { 
    position:relative;
    width: 630px; 
    height: 600px; 
    border: 0px;
    scrolling: no; 
    zoom: 1.00; 
    -ms-transform:position: absolute;
    -ms-transform:scale(0.70,0.70);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.70);
    -moz-transform-orgin: 0 0;
    -o-transform: scale(0.70);
    -o-transform-origin: 0 0; 
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.70);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
}
#emkaframe {
    position:relative;left:-110px;top:-75px;
    width:630px;
    height:630px;
    scrolling: no;
    border: 0px;
    ms-zoom: 0.70;
}